# Write a with Summation functional mixin that matches this specification

Tags: javascript

my question is Write a withSummation functional mixin that matches this specification

```
 enter code here

    "use strict";

    // Setup Mocha and Chai
    mocha.setup( "bdd" );`enter code here`
    var expect = chai.expect;

    describe( "withSummation", function(){`enter code here`
      it( "should be a function", function(){
        expect( withSummation ).to.be.a( "function" );
      } );

      it( "returns the Σ of 1 through 4", function(){
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        expect( calculator ).to.not.have.property( "sum" );
        withSummation.call( calculator );
        expect( calculator ).to.have.property( "sum" ).that.is.a( "function" );
        expect( calculator.sum( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) ).to.equal( 10 );
      } );
    } );
```

Below is my updated solution. thank you

```
    function withSummation (sum) {
  this.sum = (...arr) => {return arr.reduce((a,b) => { return a + b});
}}
```

Comment: Where did you get this `Object.prototype.addMixin` from? No, that's absolutely the wrong direction. Have a closer look again at how `withSummation` is called and what it does to the "argument".

Comment: sorry wrong solution I just edited it. the above is what I started with.

Comment: The `arrSum` wasn't bad, you should've kept it. But no, `withSummation` should not construct a `new Calculator`. Have a look at `withSummation.call( calculator );` and how the expectation around it change! You know what `call` does?

Comment: thanks, I think I got it. I edited my solution.

Comment: can you see it now.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's looking good! Except you don't need the parameter `sum`.